# How do you make -tags netgo the default for go?

Tags: go, build

To compile my golang package so that it produces a statically linked executable, I must say:

```
go install -tags netgo
```

Additionally I now realise that on a system without gcc, I must:

```
go get -tags netgo github.com/mypackage/...
go test -tags netgo ./...
```

If you're typing this all the time it's no so nice. I have aliases set up so I can type less, but is there a "nicer" or "proper" way to set -tags netgo as some kind of default? Ideally as part of my package itself, so a stranger trying to work with my package doesn't miss the -tags netgo.

Edit: I also want the possibility to say:

```
go install -tags netgo -ldflags '-linkmode external -extldflags -static -w'
```

Ie. link to C code that can be statically compiled. So it working on a machine without GCC is less important to me than it producing a statically linked executable. I just wonder if there's a way to do the latter without saying -tags netgo all the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable cgo altogether by setting `CGO_ENABLED=0` which will prevent the net package from linking to the host resolver.

Comment: Thanks, that's one way, but I should have mentioned that I want the possibility of linking to C code that has no problems being statically linked; having gcc as a requirement in that case is OK, but I still want it to be the default to build a statically compiled executable.

Comment: @sbs: then no, you have to list the tags you want to build with. Put it in a Makefile or build script. Most projects of any notable complexity end up with build requirements outside of a simple `go install`.

Comment: Can someone edit the answer to the correct `CGO_ENABLED=0`?

Comment: `CGO_ENABLED=0` may be overkill - as it disables native OS User/Group lookup as well. For example if a system is configured to resolve users via `sssd` - Go will only resolve users/groups in `/etc/passwd` & `/etc/group` - which is probably not what you want on modern OSes.